# specify execution of a set tuples in a worker node in a storm topology

Tags: apache-storm

Is it possible to execute a set of tuples (based on a particular field) on a particular worker node in the storm topology. Need to minimize network load in the cluster.

Comment: There're prepared spout/bolt which can do some caching. But it is impossible to optimise on a particular worker I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a [custom scheduler](http://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/)  ... it will allow you to bind a specific task to a supervisor , might worth taking a look into it